# difference between javac and bytecode

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javac

I understand IntelliJ does everything automatically by clicking on the little green arrow next to my Main class but I'm trying to understand what's happening underneath.

On the internet I've encountered two different things. First is the file created when we do `javac` + `my_file.java`. Second is the `Show bytecode` in the View section in the menu.
[image]

Both yield different results, so I was looking for more explanation on what those two are.

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in one post. Please [edit] to remove one of your questions.

Comment: What do you mean by they yield "different results"?

Comment: I've removed one of my questions and will post a new one. Sorry @Sweeper.

Comment: @DaveNewton What I meant is that the file I obtain after `javac myfile.java` is different than what I view when i click `Show bytecode` so I figured they both played a different role into how a .java file is processed to be executed.

Comment: Different how? What are you expecting to see in either case?

Comment: Well I was expecting to see the same file - the one that was given to the machine. I don't know much about low-level programming so I'm just wondering what those two do if they're not the same files. I'm sorry if I'm not clear.

Comment: What program are you viewing the .class file with? Most text editors will only display gibberish, since it is a binary file, not text.

Comment: @Sweeper I was using IntelliJ. I didn't know a binary file wasn't text!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`javac` produces bytecode.  That's what all JVM languages compile down to.

IntelliJ's bytecode viewer shows you a *projection* of that bytecode, since it's [normally not human readable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html).

Note that the IntelliJ tool *won't* work if the class is not compiled, since it won't actually know what the exact bytecode is.

Comment: That is much clearer now thanks! So they basically show you the same thing, just a different projection ? (I was using IntelliJ to open the bytecode produced by javac)

Comment: "Show" is a strong word...javac simply translates your code to something that the JVM can understand.  IntelliJ shows you what the compiler did if you ever need to debug down to that level.  Going to say that in my ten years of Java development, I've only ever used this as an academic curiosity more than anything serious.

Comment: Thanks!
It was an academic curiosity as well on my side. But TIL bytecode isn't just a text file and that my code is converted to bytecode before being interpreted by the machine so I guess I'll go to sleep less stupid.